# Why django can't recognize 2 path convertors from each other?

Tags: django, url, url-pattern

I have a django application and I have 2 url paths that are only different in the last part which is the path convertors:

```
path('questions/<pk>', views.QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='question_detail'),
path('questions/<slug:tag_slug>', views.QuestionListView.as_view(), name='questions_by_tag')
```

When I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/questions/1 it's ok and it shows the correct results, but when I go to 127.0.0.1:8000/questions/something(something is a slug) it says page not found!(It must use the seconed url path but it does not!)

When I change the paths order it shows the second one correctly and the other one is a problem!
Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify a path converter for `<pk>`, hence it will use the [**`<str:…>`** path converter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), and `<str:…>` is a *superset* of `<slug:…>`, hence everything that is matched by `<slug:…>` is matched by `<str:…>` as well, and thus the second pattern will never fire.

You should use the `<int:…>` path converter for integers, so:

```
path('questions/<int:pk>/', views.QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='question_detail'),
path('questions/<slug:tag_slug>/', views.QuestionListView.as_view(), name='questions_by_tag')
```